# Hugepage/Superpage support for ARMv5

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, mmu

I was looking through some recent additions to the linux kernel which added code to support 1MB Pages for ARMv6 and ARMv7, Freebsd also has support built-in since 2013 but it is also limited to ARMv6 and ARMv7. Linux also supports the usage of huge-pages to map kernel-memory on ARMv5, but not for userspace.

As I'm thinking about adding support for userspace Hugepages on ARMv5 I would like to know if there are any architectural hurdles which make it impossible to implement.

Is there a reason hugepages are not supported for userspace applications on ARMv5? Or is it just a matter of "Somebody has to implement that"? On Linux i could see that they use the former access-permission/domain bits to save some extra information, AFAICT that would not be possible on ARMv5. But is that the only reason or is there something else I might have missed?

Comment: This question is not a good fit for StackOverflow.  It doesn't have a "right" answer and even if you had an answer it's not clear how it would help solve a real-world problem.

Comment: @artlessnoise: As written, the support for 1MB-Mappings is already in the kernel (for v6+) and it is also available for the userspace. Right now I can't see a reason why it's not supported on ARMv5. My application could profit from the reduced TLB-pressure which huge-pages can provide.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Well, I'm thinking about implementing the support, but I would hate to end up being stuck on some unsolvable architectural problem which somebody might already know about.

Comment: There is no technical reason not to do it.  *okl4* para-virtualization uses many techniques to reduce/optimize MMU mappings for ARMv5.  However, it is usually specific tasked and can only work for one CPU at a time.  The ARM Linux MMU support is very generic and can function on *multiple* ARM cpus with the same run-time.  See: [ARM Linux FASS](https://lwn.net/images/conf/rtlws11/papers/proc/p01.pdf) for some ARMv5 optimizations which are never merged.

Comment: @Masta79 If you had included that in the original question it would have completely changed the tone and scope, and might not have resulted in the question being closed.

Comment: @JimGarrison: I've edited the question in hopes of it being reopened. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Comment rather than answer: there is no hardware-architecture reason why hugepages could not be supported in ARMv5 - the current code  won't support it because the translation table format changed somewhat between ARMv5 and ARMv6 - and so did all the code manipulating the translation tables. So there might be software-architecture reasons that could make the implementation tricky.

Comment: The design reasons are "generic Linux MMU" interface,   "ARM standard MMU" interface and the specific armv5 functions.  It is easy to hack-up the source to do this.  It is more difficult to support it without structural changes that affect other ARM cpus.  The TLB pressure is also probably pretty minor compared to some *FASS* features/optimizations (like using PID/Domains on ARMv5) which give *cache* benefits and this was never accepted (for various good reasons).

Comment: @artlessnoise: FASS is not practical for many applications because of the 32MByte limit.

Comment: You may default to normal page faults when outside the 32MB limit.  Most processes will be within 32MB; you actually need two of them so that the page tables need flushing/updating and hence the cache.  Ie, a context switch between two >32MB processes; libraries may map the same and DOMAINs can also be used; the 32MB is the PID function.  FASS is also limited in the number of processes.  Still, you can see some benefits?